# Rust help extracting ZIP contents

Tags: rust, unzip, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a complex file read issue....I have a need to read a DOCX file with an embedded file system, extract a ZIP file, and peruse the ZIP file's internal directory to extract the actual files I need. I already have written this code in Java successfully, so I know it can be accomplished. But, I want to do this in Rust.

Currently, I can read the DOCX file, iterate through the OLE10 objects to locate the file I need. The OLE10 file (which is actually the ZIP) has a weird  extraction command header of 256 bytes, which I seek past. If I read the rest of the file stream and write it to the filesystem it will write out as a ZIP. I can use 7-zip to open the file and see all the contents.

The problem is, no matter what Rust ZIP crate I use (zip, zip_extract, zip_extensions, rc-zip) I just cannot extract the ZIP contents. I continuously run into an issue "cannot find end of central directory". I have iterated through the file, and the EOCD tag of "50 4B 05 06" is actually there. If I end the stream at the EOCD, I got an "early end of file exit" error.  The file is >9M, and I am wondering if this might be the issue.

Anyone have any ideas how to use Rust to extract the ZIP directory and attach it to a buffer or the filesystem?

Here's the code that just won't extract:

```
let docx_path = Path::new(docx_filename);

// Capture the files from the embedded CFB filesystem
let mut comp_file = cfb::open(docx_path).unwrap();
let objpool_entries_vec: Vec<_> = comp_file                                               // Collect the entries of /ObjectPool
    .read_storage(Path::new("/ObjectPool"))
    .unwrap()
    .map(|subdir| comp_file.read_storage(subdir.path().to_owned())
        .unwrap()
        .filter(|path| path.name().contains("Ole10Native"))
        .next()
    )
    .filter(|entry| entry.is_some())                      // Filter entries with data
    .map(|entry| entry.unwrap())                               // Unwrap those entries with data
    .collect();

let mut ole10_stream = comp_file.open_stream(objpool_entries_vec[5].path())  // Create stream of the OLE10 file
    .unwrap();
ole10_stream.seek(std::io::SeekFrom::Start(256));                                           // skip the 256 byte header

let mut ole_buffer = Vec::new();
ole10_stream.read_to_end(&mut ole_buffer);

let zip_cursor = Cursor::new(ole_buffer);

zip_extract::extract(
    zip_cursor,
    &PathBuf::from("C:\\Users\\ra069466\\Documents\\Software_Projects\\Rust_projects\\ha420_maint_app\\test_files\\"),
    false)
    .unwrap();
```

When I run the following, it writes out the ZIP to the directory and I can extract with 7zip.  But, it still panics when trying to extract to the filesystem.

```
let docx_path = Path::new(docx_filename);

// Capture the files from the embedded CFB filesystem
let mut comp_file = cfb::open(docx_path).unwrap();
let objpool_entries_vec: Vec<_> = comp_file                                               // Collect the entries of /ObjectPool
    .read_storage(Path::new("/ObjectPool"))
    .unwrap()
    .map(|subdir| comp_file.read_storage(subdir.path().to_owned())
        .unwrap()
        .filter(|path| path.name().contains("Ole10Native"))
        .next()
    )
    .filter(|entry| entry.is_some())                      // Filter entries with data
    .map(|entry| entry.unwrap())                               // Unwrap those entries with data
    .collect();

let mut ole10_stream = comp_file.open_stream(objpool_entries_vec[5].path())  // Create stream of the OLE10 file
    .unwrap();
ole10_stream.seek(std::io::SeekFrom::Start(256));                                           // skip the 256 byte header

let mut ole_buffer = Vec::new();
ole10_stream.read_to_end(&mut ole_buffer);

let zip_cursor = Cursor::new(ole_buffer);    

let mut zip_file = OpenOptions::new()
    .write(true)
    .create(true)
    .open("C:\\Users\\ra069466\\Documents\\Software_Projects\\Rust_projects\\ha420_maint_app\\test_files\\test.zip")?;
zip_file.write_all(&mut zip_cursor.get_ref())?;
zip_file.flush();

let mut zip_file = File::open("C:\\Users\\ra069466\\Documents\\Software_Projects\\Rust_projects\\ha420_maint_app\\test_files\\test.zip")?;

let zip_archive = zip::ZipArchive::new(&zip_file)?;

zip_extract::extract(
    zip_file,
    &PathBuf::from("C:\\Users\\ra069466\\Documents\\Software_Projects\\Rust_projects\\ha420_maint_app\\test_files\\"),
    false)
    .unwrap();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWESOME!!  I figured it out!!
I needed to loop through the file until the 4-byte EOCD end signature of "0x50 0x4B 0x05 0x06",  then continue 17 more bytes which provides:

- "current disk#" (2-bytes),
- "CD disk#" (2-bytes),
- "# of CD disk entries on disk" (2-bytes),
- "total entries of CD" (2-byte),
- "CD size" (4-bytes),
- "CD start offset" (4-bytes),
- "# of bytes for following comments" (2-bytes),
- comments (# character bytes = previous field)

I excluded any comments, so my last two fields are 0x00 and 'blank'.  Here's the code to build the EOCD signature so I could use extract with zip_extensions::read::zip_extract():

```
let mut zip_file = OpenOptions::new()                                                      // Create the output_stream
    .write(true)
    .create(true)
    .open("C:\\Users\\ra069466\\Documents\\Software_Projects\\Rust_projects\\ha420_maint_app\\test_files\\test.zip")?;
let mut ole_iter = ole10_stream.bytes();

// loop through the ZIP file and write everything until comments
let mut data: u8;
let mut output_buffer = Vec::new();
loop
{
    match ole_iter.next()
    {
        None => break,
        Some(byte) =>
                data = byte.unwrap(),
    }

    if data == 80                                                                               // look for PK tags
    {
        let mut pk_array = [0u8; 4];
        pk_array[0] = data;
        output_buffer.push(data);
        for pk_idx in 1..4
        {
            pk_array[pk_idx] = match ole_iter.next()
            {
                None => break,
                Some(x) =>
                        x.unwrap(),
            };
            output_buffer.push(pk_array[pk_idx]);
        }

        if pk_array == [0x50, 0x4B, 0x05, 0x06]                                                           // look for PK EOCD
        {
            for x in 0..18                                                                  // read the next 17 bytes after the EOCD tag
            {
                data = match ole_iter.next()
                {
                    None => break,
                    Some(x) =>
                        x.unwrap(),
                };
                output_buffer.push(data);
            }
            break;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        output_buffer.push(data);
    }

}
zip_file.write(&mut output_buffer);
zip_file.flush();


let zip =  zip::read::ZipArchive::new(
    File::open("C:\\Users\\ra069466\\Documents\\Software_Projects\\Rust_projects\\ha420_maint_app\\test_files\\test.zip")?
)
    .unwrap();

zip_extensions::read::zip_extract(
    &PathBuf::from("C:\\Users\\ra069466\\Documents\\Software_Projects\\Rust_projects\\ha420_maint_app\\test_files\\test.zip"),
    &PathBuf::from("C:\\Users\\ra069466\\Documents\\Software_Projects\\Rust_projects\\ha420_maint_app\\test_files"),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the other crates, but `zip` will automatically be seeking to the end of whatever `io::Read` you give it (and then searching backwards). Without seeing your code, I'd guess that you're passing a reader that extends past the end of the contents of the ZIP file, so `zip` fails to recognise the contents.

Feel free to make an issue on [our issue tracker](https://github.com/zip-rs/zip/) if there's a specific feature you need. I'm happy to extend the crate's API if need be ^^

> Edit: I looked into the other crates you've used and they'd share this issue. `rc-zip` (The only one that doesn't use `zip` under the hood) has a [`ReadZip` trait](https://docs.rs/rc-zip/0.0.1/src/rc_zip/reader/read_zip.rs.html#63) that starts searching at the end of whatever buffer you give it. You'd need to call [`ArchiveReader::new`](https://docs.rs/rc-zip/0.0.1/rc_zip/struct.ArchiveReader.html#method.new) with the size you expect the internal zip file to be

Comment: Thanks, I tried rc-zip also and still have the issue of "not finding the EOCD".  But like mentioned, I can hex dump and search through the file and see the EOCD.  And, if I write the stream out, I can open it with 7zip.

Comment: It's possible that you've encountered https://github.com/zip-rs/zip/pull/178 , which will be part of the next release of the crate. It'd be great if you could share the `ole_buffer` in [a new issue](https://github.com/zip-rs/zip/issues) so that we can investigate the issue :)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide that :(
But, after reading the pull, I'm going to see if I can find the end of comment mark and stream to that point.  Maybe I can get it to to work.
Do you know why I can read the EOCD and open the rewritten ZIP in 7zip, but rs-zip does not recognize the EOCD?  Is it because of the comments?